# How do i consult these queries in prometheus?

Tags: performance, kubernetes, devops, prometheus, grafana

I'm trying to setup some graphs using prometheus with grafana in a home lab using a single node kubernetes deployed using minikube. I also have some stress test to use on the cluster. I want to measure the results of the stress test using prometheus, so i need help with the following queries:

- Cpu usage of the node/cluster and from and individual pod by given name, in a period of time (ie 5min).
- Memory usage of the node/cluster and from and individual pod by given name, in a period of time (ie 5min).
- Disk or file system usage of the node/cluster and from an individual pod by given name, in a period of time (ie 5min).
- Latency from an individual pod by given name, in a period of time (ie 5min).

If any can help with that, or know a grafana dashboard for that (i've already tried the 737 and the 6417) or give a hint of which metrics i need to consult (i've tried `rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total[5m])` and this gives me some sort of result for the cpu usage query for the whole node).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Prometheus's [labels](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/naming/#labels) to get metrics for a specific pod:

**CPU** (you don't have to provide all labels, you can select only one if that's unique:

```
sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{pod=~"<your_pod_name>", container=~"<your_container_name>", kubernetes_io_hostname=~"<your_node_name>"}[5m])) by (pod,kubernetes_io_hostname)
```

**Memory**:

```
sum(container_memory_working_set_bytes{pod=~"<your_pod_name>", container=~"<your_container_name>", kubernetes_io_hostname=~"<your_node_name>"}) by (pod,kubernetes_io_hostname)
```

**Disk**:

```
kubelet_volume_stats_used_bytes{kubernetes_io_hostname=~"<your_node_name>$", persistentvolumeclaim=~".*<your_pod_name>"}
```

**Latency**:

You can collect it in your application (web server)? via Prometheus client (application level)